# Devices working on Linux but not on Windows because of power

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive

I bought a new Medion laptop and found the first 3 devices in the list (Kobo Reader and Hotone Audio don't completely work).

Also tested on Linux and there they work correcly. Then I found out on Windows the power consumption of the devices was way too low for them to work fine:

- 2mA for the Kobo eReader (it's basically a mass storage that is not mounted on Windows)
- 64mA for the Hotone Ampero (which is an external audio card which is not recognized by it's own software)

Already tried switching cables and USB ports (2.0, 3.1 and type C and using an external hub).

Windows sais drivers and system are updated.

How could I increase the power given to the 2 devices to at least 200mA or 500mA?

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, are you testing on the same computer and booting into different operating systems?  Or, are you testing with *different* computers with different operating systems?  If testing on different computers then there's a great many things that could describe this behavior.

Comment: Testing on the same laptop and on Linux they work.

Answer (score 0):

The power available to USB devices depends on the capability of the port, and there are many variables.  A port on a powered USB host (such as a computer) can be 500 mA for a USB 1.1 port to 3000 mA for a USB 3.x port.  An "unpowered" host (meaning it relies on a battery) can provide even less power and still meet the spec.  A powered hub is supposed to provide a minimum of 500 mA per port, and an unpowered hub is supposed to provide a minimum of 100 mA per port.

One problem is that not all hubs meet the spec, not all devices meet the spec, and the same goes for hosts, drivers, cables, and anything else I may have missed.

The power allowed to a device is enforced in two ways, software and hardware.  In software the drivers and operating system will do some "bookkeeping" on how much power every USB device draws, and if some new device asks for more power than is available then the driver and OS asks that the new device not take more power.  Some drivers, operating systems, device firmware, etc. play by all the USB rules and some do not.  When they don't play by the rules then hardware protections come into play.

The hardware protections in USB ports and hubs are often self resetting fuses.  They are a bit "sloppy" on how much current they allow before cutting power so the fuses will not open up precisely when the USB spec is violated at 500 mA, 3 amps, or whatever.  They will allow for some power beyond the spec before cutting power to avoid nuisance trips.  There's many USB device manufacturers that rely on this to cut corners on how much power is drawn.  Commonly devices will not ask for any power, they will just take it.  Another common tactic is to lie to the OS how much power is drawn by claiming to be taking only 100 mA when it is taking far more.  Part of this power draw enforcement is in the driver and operating system, by changing the OS you are using different "bookkeeping" on how power is drawn.

It's going to take some investigation on who is doing this "bookkeeping" correctly and protecting your USB devices from damage.  If it works on Linux but not on Windows then it's possible Linux is doing the bookkeeping correctly and allowing every device to draw power safely.  It's possible Windows is doing the bookkeeping correctly and disallowing power to devices to protect from too much power draw.  It's possible neither are doing the power draw bookkeeping correctly.

From the screen grab in your question it appears you have many USB devices connected, and that could make diagnosis of the problem difficult.  What would help is to track down how much power each USB device draws, and how much power each US port allows.  This is just like if you see a circuit breaker trip in your home's breaker panel, you'd want to see how much power each appliance is taking and how much power each string of outlets in the house allows.

Again, not every USB device will follow the USB spec.  Those that follow the USB spec will have the USB trademarked logo on them, having the logo is part of complying with the spec.  If there is no logo then the device likely broke some other part of the spec besides not having a logo, such as taking more power than it should.

After investigating the power draw of devices, and which devices may not be adhering to the USB spec, you should be able to arrange your USB device chain into a way that functions reliably.

Comment: I tested the same devices on another Windows 10 laptop and the software says they work with the same current (2mA and 64mA), but on the other hand they do work on this new laptop. So the problem is definitely in the other laptop, his chipset, usb ports or Windows drivers.